# How to show a video in a Gtk dialog?

Tags: python, python-3.5, gtk3, gstreamer-1.0

I want to show a video in a dialog.

Therefore I create a `Gst.DrawingArea` and a `Gst.Pipeline` with a `Gst.Element` "playbin" in it.

I created a little example, it opens a window with a button.
If the button is clicked the dialog opens and should play the video.
But I only hear the audio of the video.

In another example with only a window and a DrawingArea it works fine.

Is it even possible to show a video in a Gtk.Dialog?

I am using Python 3.5.2.

Edit:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

from os import path

import gi
gi.require_version('Gst', '1.0')
gi.require_version('Gtk', '3.0')
gi.require_version('GdkX11', '3.0')
gi.require_version('GstVideo', '1.0')
from gi.repository import Gst, Gtk, GLib, GdkX11, GstVideo

from gi.repository import GObject


GObject.threads_init()
Gst.init(None)
filename = "/path/to/movie.avi"
uri = 'file://' + filename


class DialogExample(Gtk.Dialog):

def __init__(self, parent):
    Gtk.Dialog.__init__(self, "My Dialog", parent, 0,
        (Gtk.STOCK_CANCEL, Gtk.ResponseType.CANCEL,
         Gtk.STOCK_OK, Gtk.ResponseType.OK))

    self.drawingarea = Gtk.DrawingArea.new()

    self.drawingarea.connect('draw', self.on_draw)
    #self.drawingarea.connect('realize', self.on_realize)
    self.drawingarea.connect('unrealize', self.on_unrealize)
    self.drawingarea.set_size_request(800, 600)
    self.set_default_size(1000, 800)

    self.btn_Play = Gtk.Button.new_with_label("Play")
    self.btn_Play.connect('clicked', self.on_click)

    box = self.get_content_area()
    box.add(self.drawingarea)
    box.add(self.btn_Play)

    # Create GStreamer pipeline
    self.pipeline = Gst.Pipeline()

    # Create bus to get events from GStreamer pipeline
    self.bus = self.pipeline.get_bus()
    self.bus.add_signal_watch()
    self.bus.connect('message::eos', self.on_eos)
    self.bus.connect('message::error', self.on_error)

    # This is needed to make the video output in our DrawingArea:
    self.bus.enable_sync_message_emission()
    self.bus.connect('sync-message::element', self.on_sync_message)

    # Create GStreamer elements
    self.playbin = Gst.ElementFactory.make('playbin', None)

    # Add playbin to the pipeline
    self.pipeline.add(self.playbin)

    # Set properties
    self.playbin.set_property('uri', uri)

    self.show_all()


def on_click(self, button):
    if self.playbin.get_state(0).state == Gst.State.PAUSED:
        self.pipeline.set_state(Gst.State.PLAYING)
        button.set_label("Stop")
    else:
        self.pipeline.set_state(Gst.State.PAUSED)
        button.set_label("Play")

def on_realize(self, widget, data=None):
    print("on_relaize")

    window = widget.get_window()
    self.xid = window.get_xid()
    self.playbin.set_window_handle(self.xid)


def on_draw(self, widget, cr):
    print("ondraw", self.playbin.get_state(0).state)
    if self.playbin.get_state(0).state < Gst.State.PAUSED:
        allocation = widget.get_allocation()

        cr.set_source_rgb(0, 0, 0)
        cr.rectangle(0, 0, allocation.width, allocation.height)
        cr.fill()

    self.on_realize(widget)


def on_unrealize(self, widget, data=None):
    # to prevent racing conditions when closing the window while playing
    self.playbin.set_state(Gst.State.NULL)
    self.pipeline.set_state(Gst.State.NULL)

def on_sync_message(self, bus, msg):
    if msg.get_structure().get_name() == 'prepare-window-handle':
        print('prepare-window-handle')

        print('on_sync', self.xid)

        print(msg)
        print(msg.src)


def on_eos(self, bus, msg):
    print('on_eos(): seeking to start of video')
    self.pipeline.seek_simple(
        Gst.Format.TIME,
        Gst.SeekFlags.FLUSH | Gst.SeekFlags.KEY_UNIT,
        0
    )

def on_error(self, bus, msg):
    print('on_error():', msg.parse_error())



class DialogWindow(Gtk.Window):

def __init__(self):
    Gtk.Window.__init__(self, title="Dialog Example")

    self.set_border_width(6)

    button = Gtk.Button("Open dialog")
    button.connect("clicked", self.on_button_clicked)

    self.add(button)



def on_button_clicked(self, widget):
    dialog = DialogExample(self)


    response = dialog.run()

    if response == Gtk.ResponseType.OK:
        print("The OK button was clicked")
    elif response == Gtk.ResponseType.CANCEL:
        print("The Cancel button was clicked")

    dialog.destroy()


win = DialogWindow()
win.connect("delete-event", Gtk.main_quit)
win.show_all()
Gtk.main()
```

Edit 2:
[UI after I pressed the play button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LBNBR.png)

Answer (score 2):

Maybe your **drawingarea** are not calling the on_realize method...
I have the same error and decided to force it, in my code stayed this way:

```
def on_realize(self, widget):
    print("on realize")
    window = widget.get_window()
    window_handle = window.get_xid()
    self.player.set_window_handle(window_handle)

def on_draw(self, widget, cr):
    print("ondraw",self.player.get_state(0).state)
    if self.player.get_state(0).state < Gst.State.PAUSED:
        allocation = widget.get_allocation()

        cr.set_source_rgb(0, 0, 0)
        cr.rectangle(0, 0, allocation.width, allocation.height)
        cr.fill()

    self.on_realize(widget)
```

this way, when it fininsh the ondraw, automatically call on_realize method

i try your code and after the modification descripted in coments below, it  got this way

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

from os import path

import gi
gi.require_version('Gst', '1.0')
gi.require_version('Gtk', '3.0')
gi.require_version('GdkX11', '3.0')
gi.require_version('GstVideo', '1.0')
from gi.repository import Gst, Gtk, GLib, GdkX11, GstVideo

from gi.repository import GObject


GObject.threads_init()
Gst.init(None)
filename = "/home/eduardo/Downloads/tears_of_steel_1080p.webm"
uri = 'file://' + filename


class DialogExample(Gtk.Dialog):

    def __init__(self, parent):
        Gtk.Dialog.__init__(self, "My Dialog", parent, 0,
            (Gtk.STOCK_CANCEL, Gtk.ResponseType.CANCEL,
             Gtk.STOCK_OK, Gtk.ResponseType.OK))

        self.drawingarea = Gtk.DrawingArea.new()

        self.drawingarea.connect('draw', self.on_draw)
        self.drawingarea.connect('realize', self.on_realize)
        self.drawingarea.connect('unrealize', self.on_unrealize)
        self.drawingarea.set_size_request(800, 600)
        self.set_default_size(1000, 800)

        self.btn_Play = Gtk.Button.new_with_label("Play")
        self.btn_Play.connect('clicked', self.on_click)

        box = self.get_content_area()
        box.add(self.drawingarea)
        box.add(self.btn_Play)

        # Create GStreamer pipeline
        self.pipeline = Gst.Pipeline()

        # Create bus to get events from GStreamer pipeline
        self.bus = self.pipeline.get_bus()
        self.bus.add_signal_watch()
        self.bus.connect('message::eos', self.on_eos)
        self.bus.connect('message::error', self.on_error)

        # This is needed to make the video output in our DrawingArea:
        self.bus.enable_sync_message_emission()
        self.bus.connect('sync-message::element', self.on_sync_message)

        # Create GStreamer elements
        self.playbin = Gst.ElementFactory.make('playbin', None)

        # Add playbin to the pipeline
        self.pipeline.add(self.playbin)

        # Set properties
        self.playbin.set_property('uri', uri)

        self.show_all()


    def on_click(self, button):
        if self.playbin.get_state(0).state != Gst.State.PAUSED:
            self.pipeline.set_state(Gst.State.PLAYING)
            button.set_label("Stop")
        else:
            self.pipeline.set_state(Gst.State.PAUSED)
            button.set_label("Play")

    def on_realize(self, widget, data=None):
        print("on_relaize")

        window = widget.get_window()
        self.xid = window.get_xid()


    def on_draw(self, widget, cr):
        print("ondraw", self.playbin.get_state(0).state)
        if self.playbin.get_state(0).state < Gst.State.PAUSED:
            allocation = widget.get_allocation()

            cr.set_source_rgb(0, 0, 0)
            cr.rectangle(0, 0, allocation.width, allocation.height)
            cr.fill()

#       self.on_realize(widget)


    def on_unrealize(self, widget, data=None):
        # to prevent racing conditions when closing the window while playing
        self.playbin.set_state(Gst.State.NULL)
        self.pipeline.set_state(Gst.State.NULL)

    def on_sync_message(self, bus, msg):
        if msg.get_structure().get_name() == 'prepare-window-handle':
            print('prepare-window-handle')

            print('on_sync', self.xid)
            self.playbin.set_window_handle(self.xid)

            print(msg)
            print(msg.src)


    def on_eos(self, bus, msg):
        print('on_eos(): seeking to start of video')
        self.pipeline.seek_simple(
            Gst.Format.TIME,
            Gst.SeekFlags.FLUSH | Gst.SeekFlags.KEY_UNIT,
            0
        )

    def on_error(self, bus, msg):
        print('on_error():', msg.parse_error())



class DialogWindow(Gtk.Window):

    def __init__(self):
        Gtk.Window.__init__(self, title="Dialog Example")

        self.set_border_width(6)

        button = Gtk.Button("Open dialog")
        button.connect("clicked", self.on_button_clicked)

        self.add(button)



    def on_button_clicked(self, widget):
        dialog = DialogExample(self)


        response = dialog.run()

        if response == Gtk.ResponseType.OK:
            print("The OK button was clicked")
        elif response == Gtk.ResponseType.CANCEL:
            print("The Cancel button was clicked")

        dialog.destroy()


win = DialogWindow()
win.connect("delete-event", Gtk.main_quit)
win.show_all()
Gtk.main()
```

Comment: Try too import this librarys

import gi
gi.require_version('Gst', '1.0')
gi.require_version('Gtk', '3.0')
gi.require_version('GdkX11', '3.0')
gi.require_version('GstVideo', '1.0')
from gi.repository import Gst, Gtk, GLib, GdkX11, GstVideo

Comment: I edited the code example above with the `on_draw` method and the missings imports. I have only forgot the GLib. I also add a Play / Stop button.
The `on_realize` method is definitely called, but the video is not shown, I only hear the audio.
Does it work in your project?

Comment: in the part of code of process buton play click we have 
    it "if self.playbin.get_state(0).state == Gst.State.PAUSED:"
you must change to 
   " if self.playbin.get_state(0).state != Gst.State.PLAYING:"
cause the pipeline starts in NULL state

Comment: I copy your code and I only change the path to the movie ( avi or mkv file). I add a picture above, which shows the UI after I press the play button. I can hear the audio of the movie but the movie itself is invisble.
Do i miss some modules or packages ?
I use Linux Mint 18.1 with Cinnamon

Comment: comment this line and say to me if it run with image in other window  [self.bus.connect('sync-message::element', self.on_sync_message)]

Comment: I commented it out and I can hear and see the video in a new window.

Comment: i had the same error when placing drawingarea in a fixed widget ..
Try to put a Layout widget in the box before a drawing area or change this box widget.. maybe it works fine this is what i did.
i cant try it be cause your code works fine here, im using ubuntu xenial 14.6 if im not wrong, you can try to reinstall the gstreamer plugins maybe it can work this way

Comment: Thanks a lot for your replays. I tried it with Ubuntu 16.04 in a VM and there the mini example is runnging fine, audio and video in the dialog. I have reinstalled the plugins in the Linux Mint OS, but it does not help. I think I need to compare the packages one by one...
At the first look, i see that the gstreamer plugins have the same version.

Comment: Hi, any ideas to replace the GdkX11, since I am using a mac? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This is another way, using gstreamer's `gtksink`. This should even work if a "nasty" compositor is running (as the asker mentioned problems in Linux Mint using Cinnamon):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import gi
gi.require_version("Gtk", "3.0")
gi.require_version("Gst", "1.0")
from gi.repository import Gtk, Gst

import os, sys

Gst.init(None)
Gst.init_check(None)


class PlayerWidget(Gtk.Box):
    """ This is the gtksink widget """
    def __init__(self, parent):
        super().__init__()
        self.parent = parent
        self.player = Gst.ElementFactory.make("playbin")

        self.connect('realize', self.on_realize)

    def on_realize(self, widget):
        playerFactory = self.player.get_factory()
        gtksink = playerFactory.make('gtksink')
        self.player.set_property("video-sink", gtksink)

        self.pack_start(gtksink.props.widget, True, True, 0)
        gtksink.props.widget.show()


class VideoDialog(Gtk.Dialog):
    def __init__(self, parent, filename):
        Gtk.Dialog.__init__(self, "VideoDialog", parent, 0,
                            (Gtk.STOCK_CANCEL, Gtk.ResponseType.CANCEL,
                             Gtk.STOCK_OK, Gtk.ResponseType.OK))
        self.filename = filename
        self.__setupUi()

    def __setupUi(self):
        self.set_default_size(800, 400)

        self.playerWidget = PlayerWidget(parent=self)
        self.playerWidget.set_size_request(800, 450)

        self.player = self.playerWidget.player
        self.player.set_property("uri", self.filename)

        self.btnPlay = Gtk.Button(label="Play")
        self.btnPlay.connect("clicked", self.on_btnPlay_clicked)

        self.hboxBtn01 = Gtk.Box()
        self.hboxBtn01.add(self.btnPlay)

        self.vbox_intern = self.get_content_area()
        self.vbox_intern.add(self.playerWidget)
        self.vbox_intern.add(self.hboxBtn01)

        self.show_all()

    def on_btnPlay_clicked(self, widget):
        playerState = self.player.get_state(Gst.SECOND).state
        if playerState <= Gst.State.PAUSED:
            self.player.set_state(Gst.State.PLAYING)
            self.btnPlay.set_label("Pause")
        elif playerState is Gst.State.PLAYING:
            self.player.set_state(Gst.State.PAUSED)
            self.btnPlay.set_label("Play")


class MainWindow(Gtk.Window):
    def __init__(self):
        Gtk.Window.__init__(self, title="Open VideoDialog")

        self.filename = "https://www.freedesktop.org/software/gstreamer-sdk" + \
                                        "/data/media/sintel_trailer-480p.webm"
        self.set_border_width(40)
        self.set_default_size(200, 110)
        button = Gtk.Button("Don't push the button!")
        button.connect("clicked", self.on_button_clicked)
        self.add(button)

    def on_button_clicked(self, widget):
        videoDialog = VideoDialog(self, self.filename)
        videoDialog.set_transient_for(self)
        videoDialog.set_modal(True)

        if Gtk.ResponseType.OK == videoDialog.run():
            print("Response: OK")
        else:
            print("Response: Cancel")

        videoDialog.player.set_state(Gst.State.NULL)
        videoDialog.destroy()

win = MainWindow()
win.connect("destroy", Gtk.main_quit)
win.show_all()
Gtk.main()
```

EDIT:
It seems that in debian-based distros gstreamer's gtksink is not in the package it belongs to (that is [gst-plugins-good](https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/data/doc/gstreamer/head/gst-plugins-good/html/gst-plugins-good-plugins-gtksink.html)). On Debian 9 it is part of `gst-plugins-bad`(?). On Ubuntu 18.04 `gst-inspect1.0 gtksink` claims it to be part of `gst-plugins-good` but it isn't. It's in `gstreamer1.0-gtk3`. So you would have to install ...?

Comment: how to play local url file::/// ?

Comment: @vishal-mote: Change self.filename (in class MainWindow) to your local URL.
Example: self.filename = "file:///home/<your username>/path/to/file"

Answer (score 0):

vishal-mote, I just added file chooser dialog and added uri/url encoding to file:// so that gtk application play the selected video.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

gi.require_version("Gtk", "3.0")
gi.require_version("Gst", "1.0")
from gi.repository import Gtk, Gst
from urllib.parse import urlparse 
from urllib.parse import quote
import os, sys

Gst.init(None)
Gst.init_check(None)


class PlayerWidget(Gtk.Box):
    """ This is the gtksink widget """
    def __init__(self, parent):
        super().__init__()
        self.parent = parent
        self.player = Gst.ElementFactory.make("playbin")

        self.connect('realize', self.on_realize)

    def on_realize(self, widget):
        playerFactory = self.player.get_factory()
        gtksink = playerFactory.make('gtksink')
        self.player.set_property("video-sink", gtksink)

        self.pack_start(gtksink.props.widget, True, True, 0)
        gtksink.props.widget.show()


class VideoDialog(Gtk.Dialog):
    def __init__(self, parent, filename):
        Gtk.Dialog.__init__(self, "VideoDialog", parent, 0,
                            (Gtk.STOCK_CANCEL, Gtk.ResponseType.CANCEL,
                             Gtk.STOCK_OK, Gtk.ResponseType.OK))
        self.filename = filename
        self.__setupUi()

    def __setupUi(self):
        self.set_default_size(800, 400)

        self.playerWidget = PlayerWidget(parent=self)
        self.playerWidget.set_size_request(800, 450)

        self.player = self.playerWidget.player
        self.player.set_property("uri", self.filename)

        self.btnPlay = Gtk.Button(label="Play")
        self.btnPlay.connect("clicked", self.on_btnPlay_clicked)

        self.hboxBtn01 = Gtk.Box()
        self.hboxBtn01.add(self.btnPlay)

        self.vbox_intern = self.get_content_area()
        self.vbox_intern.add(self.playerWidget)
        self.vbox_intern.add(self.hboxBtn01)

        self.show_all()



    def on_btnPlay_clicked(self, widget):
        playerState = self.player.get_state(Gst.SECOND).state
        if playerState <= Gst.State.PAUSED:
            self.player.set_state(Gst.State.PLAYING)
            self.btnPlay.set_label("Pause")
        elif playerState is Gst.State.PLAYING:
            self.player.set_state(Gst.State.PAUSED)
            self.btnPlay.set_label("Play")


class MainWindow(Gtk.Window):
    def __init__(self):
        Gtk.Window.__init__(self, title="Open VideoDialog")

        self.filename = "https://www.freedesktop.org/software/gstreamer-sdk" + \
                                        "/data/media/sintel_trailer-480p.webm"
        self.set_border_width(40)
        self.set_default_size(200, 110)
        button = Gtk.Button("Choose File!")
        button.connect("clicked", self.on_file_clicked)
        self.add(button)
        #uncomment below to start the player as if button is pressed
        #self.on_button_clicked(Gtk.Button)
        
        
        
    def on_file_clicked(self, widget):
        dialog = Gtk.FileChooserDialog(
            title="Please choose a file", parent=self, action=Gtk.FileChooserAction.OPEN
        )
        dialog.add_buttons(
            Gtk.STOCK_CANCEL,
            Gtk.ResponseType.CANCEL,
            Gtk.STOCK_OPEN,
            Gtk.ResponseType.OK,
        )

        self.add_filters(dialog)

        response = dialog.run()
        if response == Gtk.ResponseType.OK:
            print("Open clicked")
            print("File selected: " + dialog.get_filename())
            self.filename = quote(dialog.get_filename())
            #encode URI to file://<path+filename>
            self.filename = "file://"+self.filename
            print(self.filename)
            # when the file is selected cose the file dialog
            dialog.destroy()
            self.on_button_clicked(Gtk.Button)
            
        elif response == Gtk.ResponseType.CANCEL:
            print("Cancel clicked")

        dialog.destroy()

    def add_filters(self, dialog):
        filter_video = Gtk.FileFilter()
        filter_video.set_name("Video File")
        filter_video.add_mime_type("video/*")
        dialog.add_filter(filter_video)

        filter_any = Gtk.FileFilter()
        filter_any.set_name("Any files")
        filter_any.add_pattern("*")
        dialog.add_filter(filter_any)
        
        

    def on_button_clicked(self, widget):
        videoDialog = VideoDialog(self, self.filename)
        videoDialog.set_transient_for(self)
        videoDialog.set_modal(True)

        if Gtk.ResponseType.OK == videoDialog.run():
            print("Response: OK")
        else:
            print("Response: Cancel")

        videoDialog.player.set_state(Gst.State.NULL)
        videoDialog.destroy()

win = MainWindow()
win.connect("destroy", Gtk.main_quit)
win.show_all()
Gtk.main()
```